# Create file and folders defined in file

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, batch-file

Good morning, I'm trying to create folders and empty files from a text file.
Per example, I have a *create.txt* with the following content:

```
FolderA
FolderA\FolderB
FolderA\FileC.js
```

I know that I can create folders from a text file with the following command line:

```
FOR /F %i in (test.txt) do md %i
```

I know that I can create files (with only a new line) with the following command line:

```
FOR /F %i in (test.txt) do echo.> %i
```

Now I would like a batch script that can know when it's a file or a folder to create it respectly. I thought this might work, but it does not even run something...

```
FOR /F %i in (test.txt) do findstr %i".">Nul && ( echo.> %i ) || ( md %i )
```

I can solve this problem by implementing a Java or C++ or something program to do that, by the idea is to be independent of a programming language.

Can somebody share a script for this problem?
In my case, I'm using Windows but for people who uses the unix shell, can somebody share a script for them too?

Comment: How do you differentiate between a folder or a file (at the end of a path). So if there is a line in your _create.txt_ like: _FolderA\FolderB\...\Something_ What is _Something_? A folder or a file? Same thing for e.g.: _Something.ext_.

Comment: All files and folders defined as a string in a file, I see a file when it has an extension. The extension comes after a ".", and I don't have any folders with a ".".

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
For /F %I In (test.txt) Do @If %~nxI==%~nI @(MD %I) Else @(Type Nul>%I)
```

Comment: It works nice, thank you very much. Do you know how to do it in the Unix shell too?

Comment: @Moreira Do you need the Unix version? The question states that you don’t. If someone else needs the Unix version, they can ask independently.